# C# Console App - This operation requires an interactive window station

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a C# console that is scheduled to execute in windows task scheduler.  When I try to run it from the scheduler, the schedule give me the following error:

This operation requires an interactive window station.

WHat I noticed is that this app uses a app.manifest so that it can make the following call:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", <PARAM to FileZilla Server.exe /reload_config>);
```

If I take the app.manifest out then it would launch fine from task scheduler.

If I leave app.manifest in and run it by clicking on the app, it launches fine. (but not from task scheduler)

Answer (score 3):

Found something related to this error, hope it helps.

> The reason why Windows require the tasks to run in interactive mode is because it was suppose to show an elevated prompt prior to running the tasks itself, thanks to UAC. This is also the reason why the error only happens when the scheduled tasks are configured to run with non build-in Administrator account, by default the built-in Administrator account is configured with silent UAC policy.
>
> To enable the silent UAC policy to non built-in Administrator account (account other than Administrator in Administrators group), open up the Properties page for the scheduled tasks, and check the Run with Highest Priveleges checkbox. This will cause the tasks to be executed as elevated a.k.a as Administrator. Case Closed.

from [Interactive Window Station Error On Scheduled Tasks](https://irongeek.wordpress.com/2008/12/02/interactive-window-station-error-on-scheduled-tasks/)

Comment: I have the "Run with Highest Preveleges" checked but it still gives the same error.